# QGIS and use of Python/R

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, r, data, rqgis

I am very new to spatial econometrics. I have two quick questions about QGIS. Is QGIS Python powered? Do I need to learn Python for QGIS or knowledge of R will be sufficient to use QGIS? I don't know Python but very recently I have started learning R, hence the question.

Comment: You **need** Python for QGIS like you need C++ for Microsoft Word. QGIS is a GUI application, which you'll see if you try it, and you don't need any programming language at all. You only *need* a lower level language if you are writing extensions or working on the source code. When you get to that point and get stuck, write a new question!

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html

Answer (score 1):

QGIS tools run based on C++ and not Python, as MrXsquared and marcelo pointed me out. Still, you don't need to know any programming language to use the tools. The GUI is sufficient for many tasks. In addition the "syntax" of the field calculator is explained quite well.

Still, learning Python can be sensible, especially if you need to accomplish very specialized tasks which go beyond the standard tools.

Comment: Arent the native processing tools written in C++?

Comment: I thought it was Python, since you can add your own Python-scripts etc, but I may be wrong, sure.

Comment: QGIS is written on C++. But it has Python API (so we can use it to write Python plugins).